# A better way to see if a variable isset php

Tags: php, php-5.3

Hi I just was wondering if there is a better way to do something like this:

```
$openid = $_SESSION['openiduserdata'];
if (isset($openid['namePerson/friendly']))
    {$username = $openid['namePerson/friendly'];}
if (isset($openid['namePerson/first']))
    {$firstname = $openid['namePerson/first'];}
if (isset($openid['namePerson/last']))
    {$lastname = $openid['namePerson/last'];}
if (isset($openid['birthDate']))
    {$birth = $openid['birthDate'];}
if (isset($openid['contact/postalCode/home']))
    {$postcode = $openid['contact/postalCode/home'];}
if (isset($openid['contact/country/home']))
    {$country = $openid['contact/country/home'];}
if (isset($openid['contact/email']))
    {$email = $openid['contact/email'];}
```

Comment: It's unclear how you want to deal with defaults in your example code (looks like you later need to probe each variable again for existence). But you might want to use an array map instead of individual `if` statements.

Comment: I have a question: Why you need to put in memory the same values three times?  $_SESSION['openiduserdata'], $openid and $username and others.

Answer (score 5):

```
$variables = array('openid' => 'openiduserdata', 'username' => 'namePerson/friendly', 'firstname' => 'namePerson/first', 'lastname' => 'namePerson/last', 'birth' => 'birthDate', 'postcode' => 'contact/postalCode/home', 'country' => 'contact/country/home', 'email' => 'contact/email');

foreach ($variables as $name => $key)
  if (isset($openid[$key]))
    $$name = $openid[$key];
```

Comment: variable variables... I can't bring myself to upvote any solution that uses them, even if it is probably the best idea.

Comment: I don't blame you for the gut feeling, but in this case, the variable names are coming from a hardcoded array, not user input or anything similarly dangerous. The programmer has defined the variable names just the same.

Comment: Yeah, I know... but still... ugh.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to avoid PHP notices, just prefix the array variable with `@`:

```
$username = @$openid['namePerson/friendly'];
```

Comment: Wow dude really? This is a horrible practice and can lead to long nights of "white page debugging" later on.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Quite the opposite actually. OPs original code snippet will ***never*** emit a single traceable note. But the @-suppressed notices can still be redisplayed when needed (as log, with a custom error handler). Not that it matters ***at all*** in this case.

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly mario. You assume that the OP will remember to look for `@` every time something isn't working. It's a bad habit to get into, suppressing notice/warnings instead of proper error checking and failsaving.

Comment: For example, when the goal is "assign this `$_POST` variable to this other variable" and you are going to test if the other variable is set later, the `isset()` check on the `$_POST` array element is redundant.  Using `@` is perfectly acceptable when used judiciously.  In this particular case, the difference between using `@` as I suggest and using the OP's code is absolutely nothing, assuming that the variables being assigned to didn't already have some value.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Let's disregard the fictional cases for once and asses what actual error you are possibly fixing here. Making undefined input variables *entirely undebugable* with heaps of `isset` isn't helpful in my book.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set only those options that are not set in the array to a default value, one solution would be to create an array containing all of the default values, and then merge the incoming array with the default array.

```
<?php    
$defaults = array('name' => 'Anonymous','gender' => 'n/a');
$data = array_merge($defaults, $_POST);
// now data includes all the post parameters, however, those parameters that don't exist will be the default value in $data
```

Comment: +1 from me. I misread your answer before posting mine which has exactly the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create function just like this:

```
function get_value_or_default($array, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array))
    {
        return $array[$key];
    }
    else
    {
        return $default;
    }
}

$username = get_value_or_default($openid, 'namePerson/friendly');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$openid = array_merge(
   array('namePerson/friendly' => NULL,   // Or an empty string if you prefer.
         'namePerson/first'    => NULL,
         'namePerson/last'     => NULL),  // etc.
   $_SESSION['openiduserdata']);

// Now you know that the keys are set.
// Then if you really need them separate:
$username = openid['namePerson/friendly'];
$firstname = openid['namePerson/first'];
$lastname = openid['namePerson/last'];
// etc.
```